# Check if any file with an extension exists on SFTP server using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

What is the C# code to check if any `.xls` files are in a remote SFTP folder using WinSCP .NET assembly?  The `xls` files have different names, I only know the files I want will have am `xls` file extension.

```
string strFileRemote = @"/folder/*.xls";
// Set up session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = sftpHost,
    UserName = sftpUsername,
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "value for finger print",
    SshPrivateKeyPath = @"\\file server\.ppk",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Upload files
    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
    // Download
    transferResult =
        session.GetFiles(strFileRemote, strFileLocal, false, transferOptions);

    // Throw on any error
    transferResult.Check();
    if (transferResult.IsSuccess == false)
    {
        strStatus = "Error: " + transferResult.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not just `Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles()` (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [WinSCP article on Checking file existence](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence#library), use [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) to check, if any file matching a mask exists on am SFTP server:

```
bool anyXmlExists =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/folder", "*.xml", EnumerationOptions.None).Any();
```